# How to plot using a factorial variable as the background colour with ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I am plotting some data (Y= `Variable.A`) over time (X= `Datetime`) using `ggplot2`. I also have a variable called `Photoperiod` which indicates if this `Datetime` belongs to the `Day`, `Sunrise`, `Sunset` or `Night`. For interpretation purposes, I would like to colour the background of my plot with different colours depending on the `Photoperiod` to find patterns associated with this. Below I share some fake data.

```
df <- data.frame(Datetime = seq(from=as.POSIXct("2012-01-01 08:00", tz="UTC"),to=as.POSIXct("2012-01-08 07:00", tz="UTC"),by="hour"),
                    Variable.A = sample(seq(from = 0, to = 4.9, by = 0.1), size = 168, replace = TRUE),
                    Photoperiod = rep(rep(c("Day","Sunset","Night","Sunrise"), c(12, 2, 8, 2)), length.out = 168))

head(df)
             Datetime Variable.A Photoperiod
1 2012-01-01 08:00:00        2.9         Day
2 2012-01-01 09:00:00        4.2         Day
3 2012-01-01 10:00:00        2.0         Day
4 2012-01-01 11:00:00        0.8         Day
5 2012-01-01 12:00:00        2.6         Day
6 2012-01-01 13:00:00        2.9         Day
```

Here I share the code I get so far to make the plot I desire:

```
ggplot(data = df)+ 
  aes(x=Datetime, y=Variable.A) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(size=1.5) + 
  labs(x='Date',y="\n ID") + 
  coord_capped_cart(bottom="both",left="both") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(strip.background=element_blank(),
        axis.title.x =element_text(margin = margin(t = 12, r = 20, b = 0, l = 0),size = 16),
        axis.title.y =element_text(margin = margin(t = 2, r = 20, b = 0, l = 0),size = 16),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1,size = 12),
        axis.text.y = element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 0.5,size = 14),
        strip.text.x = element_text(size = 14),
        strip.text.y = element_text(size = 13),
        axis.line = element_line(),
        panel.grid.major= element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        legend.text=element_text(size=12),
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.key=element_blank(),
        legend.position = "top",
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        strip.placement = "outside") +
  scale_x_datetime(breaks = "6 hour") + 
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=3.5)))
```

[image]

As I already said, I would like to colour the background according to the `Photoperiod` level to identify easily cyclical patterns.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really the best solution, since you will need to adjust the values a bit, but I used it before. You basically draw tiles onto the plot. Hope this helps anyways.

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(Datetime = seq(from=as.POSIXct("2012-01-01 08:00", tz="UTC"),to=as.POSIXct("2012-01-08 07:00", tz="UTC"),by="hour"),
                 Variable.A = sample(seq(from = 0, to = 4.9, by = 0.1), size = 168, replace = TRUE),
                 Photoperiod = rep(rep(c("Day","Sunset","Night","Sunrise"), c(12, 2, 8, 2)), length.out = 168))
ggplot(data = df)+ 
  aes(x=Datetime, y=as.numeric(Variable.A)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill=Photoperiod, y= mean(Variable.A)), size=max(df$Variable.A+1), alpha = 0.5, height=max(df$Variable.A+1))+
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(size=1.5) + 
  labs(x='Date',y="\n ID") + 
  #  coord_capped_cart(bottom="both",left="both") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(strip.background=element_blank(), axis.title.x =element_text(margin =
  margin(t = 12, r = 20, b = 0, l = 0),size = 16), axis.title.y
  =element_text(margin = margin(t = 2, r = 20, b = 0, l = 0),size = 16),
  axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1,size = 12), axis.text.y =
  element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 0.5,size = 14), strip.text.x =
  element_text(size = 14), strip.text.y = element_text(size = 13), axis.line =
  element_line(), panel.grid.major= element_blank(), panel.grid.minor =
  element_blank(), legend.text=element_text(size=12), legend.title =
  element_blank(), legend.key=element_blank(), legend.position = "top",
  panel.border = element_blank(), strip.placement = "outside") +
  scale_x_datetime(breaks = "6 hour")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

## Edit

You will have a better effect if you place the   `geom_tile(aes(fill=Photoperiod, y= mean(Variable.A), size=10, alpha = 0.5, height=max(Variable.A+1)))` before the `geom_line()`

Comment: Thanks @MKR. I don't know why but I get "1: Removed 168 rows containing missing values (geom_tile)" when I run your code in my real scenario, and thus, the colours are not plotted...

Comment: Not sure why. Try the "onion" approach:
Start with: `geom_tile(aes(fill=Photoperiod))` and continue adding the different arguments one by one and see where the problem is.

Comment: Thanks for your idea @MKR. I found out the problem: I have some NAs for my `Variable.A`, and then the colours are not plotted. Do you know how to solve that? Thanks for your time by the way.

Comment: I am not sure if I can give you a good solution for how to handle NA values. That depends on the question. You could either exclude them for the plot, or you could give it a colour with `scale_fill_continuous(na.value = 'blue')

Comment: And is there a way to remove from the legend the values `0.5` and `5.9`?

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake from my side: ggplot draws legends for variables inside the `aes()` statement. I falsely put `size`, `alpha`, and `height` inside `aes()`, even though these are not strictly dependent on the data. I have updated the code in the original post.